# Computing Hochschild Invariants of Positselski's Coderived Categories

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hochschild-homology, koszul-duality

Positselski's work allows one to frame Koszul duality very elegantly in terms of so called coderived categories of modules over coalgebras, these are somewhat exotic dg categories of comodules over $C$ in which certain acyclic complexes survive.

The reader can consult https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2621 for a detailed exposition.

My question, if I have a coalgebra $C$, is there an explicit, and ideally "fairly small" complex, defined from $C$, which computes the Hochschild (co-) homology of the coderived category of comodules for $C$?

Comment: A relevant reference is our paper A.Polishchuk, L.Positselski "Hochschild (co)homology of the second kind I", Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 364 (2012), https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0982 , in which Hochschild homology and cohomology theories loosely associated with derived categories of the second kind are defined for CDG-algebras and CDG-modules.

Comment: Hochschild homology and perhaps also cohomology of the second kind for a CDG-coalgebra would be an even more natural and better behaved construction, closely related to the coderived categories of CDG-comodules (and perhaps also the contraderived categories of CDG-contramodules).  This looks quite doable, but it appears that noone has done it yet.